# Not enough arguments for format string Error

Tags: python

The below snippet of code gives me "TypeError: not enough arguments for format string"

```
params = ()
message = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/auditLogs/signIns?$filter=createdDateTime+ge+2020-01-14T08%3a33%3a00Z+and+createdDateTime+lt+2020-01-14T11%3a53%3a00Z&top=1&$skiptoken=98c04a437a5d4d5280ed1bae48ce6dbe_1'
st = (message % params)
print(st)
```

But if I replace the message with 'hello' it works. Not able to figure out what is causing the problem and how to fix it?

Comment: You need to escape any literal `%` characters.

Comment: Where do you expect the params to go into the string?